# How to transform php array with objects into simple array?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a function that returns an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1
            [vid] => 2
            [name] => About Us
            [description] => 
            [format] => wysiwyg_editor
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 200
        [vid] => 2
        [name] => Stories
        [description] => 
        [format] => wysiwyg_editor
        [weight] => 0
        [depth] => 0
        [parents] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )
```

)

To simplify it for further use I would like to convert this array into simple one with keys as [tid] and values as [name]
So it would be smth like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => About Us
    [200] => Stories
```

)

Any tips or help with proper code syntax would be great. Thanks

Comment: Loop through the entries, set the key in some new array to `$entry->tid` and the value to `$entry->name`. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: None of the tutorials I had found for this included all of this elements together, so I decided to ask for help.  I don't clearly understand the nature of objects at this time... Thanks!

Comment: @ijujym Then please ask targeted questions about what you don't understand instead of asking big-picture-please-give-me-a-solution questions. Chances are you can answer your own questions if you break them down enough, but at least chances are better that those targeted questions will be of more use for future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result[$row->tid] = $row->name;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Its a real shame that people come on SO, do no work at all and get everyone else to do it for them.  At least we should be asking what they have tried before just giving them an answer.

Comment: Shame because people don't learn by doing this, they copy and paste, go back to work, then come back here with their next problem, again getting you to just write the code for them.  Complete waste.

Comment: @Jon That's what downvoting the question is for. It will eventually block the user from posting more such questions.

Comment: @deceze it is not just one user though, the problem is fed by the fact they know people will just post code.  I can downvote this question as much as I want but it won't stop them either reregistering, or other users from doing the same.

Comment: @Jon It [*will* stop them from re-registering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998). I agree it's a problem, but not one that answerers should be punished for. Anyway, this discussion is old and rather off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

use this snippet :

```
function transform($arr){
   $result = array();

   foreach($arr as $obj){
     $result[$obj->tid] = $obj->name;
   }

   return $result;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some explination, at least help them learn.